# Issue to control WndProc function in API

Tags: c++, api

Now I'm implement a simple API program as below.

the purpose is that I want to control the WndProc function with my user defined message.

But I don't know how to do that? MessageBox() function does not work.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>



#define WIDTHBYTES(w, bitcount) ((((w)*(bitcount)+31)& ~31) >> 3)

int RAW2DIB(HWND);
unsigned char *_Orgin_Pixel_;
unsigned char *_Copy_Pixel_;
unsigned int W_Image = 750;
unsigned int H_Image = 800;
unsigned int widthbytes = WIDTHBYTES(W_Image, 8);
unsigned int S_Image = widthbytes * H_Image;
BITMAPINFO *BmInfo;



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
static HANDLE hTimer;
switch (iMessage)
{



case WM_CREATE:
return 0;

case WM_COMMAND:
switch (LOWORD(wParam))
{
case 0:

hTimer = (HANDLE)SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 10, NULL); //10ms
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, 0); 
break;

case 1:
VirtualFree(_Orgin_Pixel_, sizeof(BYTE)*(S_Image), MEM_DECOMMIT); //Memory free
VirtualFree(_Copy_Pixel_, sizeof(BYTE)*(S_Image), MEM_DECOMMIT); //Memory free
free(BmInfo); //Memory free
KillTimer(hWnd, 1);
break;

case 2:
PostQuitMessage(0);
break;
}
return 0;

case WM_TIMER:
switch (wParam)
{
case 1:
RAW2DIB(hWnd);
break;
}
return 0;
case WM_PAINT: 
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, W_Image, H_Image, 0, 0, 0, H_Image, _Copy_Pixel_, BmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS); //복사된 RAW 이미지 데이터 즉, _Copy_Pixel_를 뿌린다.
EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
return 0;
case WM_DESTROY:



VirtualFree(_Copy_Pixel_, sizeof(BYTE)*(S_Image), MEM_DECOMMIT); //Memery free
VirtualFree(_Orgin_Pixel_, sizeof(BYTE)*(S_Image), MEM_DECOMMIT);//Memery free
free(BmInfo); //Memery free
KillTimer(hWnd, 1);
PostQuitMessage(0);
return 0;

}
return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam));
}


int RAW2DIB(HWND hWnd)
{
unsigned int Picture_x_, Picture_y_, Bitdepth;
//...
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE); 
return 0;
}




INT APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, TCHAR *pszLine, INT nShow) {
HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASS wc;
MSG msg;
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hello World!"), TEXT("Title"), MB_OK);
//return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, the simplest way to do message processing (taking control) is to use `DialogBox` and a dialog resource. Otherwise you can implement a general window by calling `RegisterClass`, `CreateWindow`, `ShowWindow` and then a loop with `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`. It's technically *possible* to subclass a message box but try more basic stuff first.

Comment: By the way don't use Microsoft's monstrosity `_tWinMain`. It's wrong in a thousand plus more ways. Just use a standard `main`. And don't use the abhorrent `TEXT` macro (unless you really want to provide limited support for Windows 9x, which you can't make an executable for with Microsoft's modern tools). Just write e.g. `L"Hello"`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I just followed reference web pages.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm not familiar with this API program. actually this is the first time. So can you let me know  more?

Comment: The code you have is from a program that does someting, not a minimum example program. You need a minimum example program.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf When I run that program in VS2013,  It's run. I don't know what "minimum example program" mean.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Can't I send some message to WndProc function in the _tWinMain function?

Comment: The `WndProc` function is meant to be part of a window. It's then mostly called automatically. It does the message processing for a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways of implementing this is to use modal dialogs. Dialogs in Windows differ from other windows (that have window class) very little. Here is the sample code (it is from real project and contains some additional stuffs for displaying multiple dialogs at the same time):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK TBasicDialog::ModalDialogBoxProcedure(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TBasicDialog *inst = (TBasicDialog*)(INT_PTR)::GetWindowLong(hDlg, GWL_USERDATA);
    if (inst == NULL && message != WM_INITDIALOG)
        return(FALSE);

switch (message)
{
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
            {
                inst = (TBasicDialog*)lParam;
                ::SetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)(INT_PTR)inst);

                inst->m_hDlg = hDlg;
                inst->SetDialogIcons(NULL, inst->m_iconIdentBig, inst->m_iconIdentSmall);
                return(inst->OnInitDialog((HWND)wParam));
            }
            break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
            inst->OnWmCommand((short)LOWORD(wParam), (short)HIWORD(wParam), (HWND)lParam);
            break;

    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            inst->OnWmSysCommand((int)wParam);
            break;

    case WM_NOTIFY:
            inst->OnWmNotify((NMHDR*)lParam);
            break;

    case WM_TIMER:
            inst->OnWmTimer((int)wParam);
            break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
            {
                // Experiments with debugger show that when the button CANCEL or the Alt-F4 are pressed,
                // Windows generates WM_CLOSE event and after that it generates WM_COMMAND with IDCANCEL.
                // So, this message can be safely ignored if closing request is handled in the WM_COMMAND handler.
            }
            break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                inst->m_bInWmDestroyHandler = TRUE;
                if (inst->OnWmDestroy() == FALSE)
                {
                    // Derived class decided not to delete the object. Some of its fields should
                    // be cleared because it is necessary to allow opening it later.
                    inst->m_hDlg = NULL;
                    inst->m_ctrlsPosHelper.ResetHelper();
                    inst->m_bInWmDestroyHandler = FALSE;
                }
            }
            break;

    default:
        {
            if (message >= WM_USER && message < WM_USER+1000)
                inst->OnWmUser(message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
}

        return(FALSE);
}
```

This handler calls methods of the class to do the job, but you can call static functions or put your code inline. This is not important.

Here is how you open the dialog and wait until it is being closed.

```
retValue = (int)::DialogBoxParam(m_hInst,
                        MAKEINTRESOURCE(dialogTemplateId),
                        hParent, (DLGPROC)ModalDialogBoxProcedure,
                        (LPARAM)this);
```

This windows API `DialogBoxParam` can be called from anywhere. `WinMain` (or `_tWinMain`) are perfectly fine for that.

The benefits of dialogs is that you do not need to register any windows class and that Windows will rotate the message loop for you. From other points of view dialogs are the same to windows.

Dialogs require dialog template. But at the same time these templates are easy way to have windows with some simple message and a couple of buttons.

Comment: Thanks so much. but especially your answer is very tremendous to me. Is that possible to control in _tWinMain() function? I just want to control that WndProc function  in _tWinMain() function.

Comment: I updated a bit. Remove all the stuffs that you do not need from my sample. Finally you will get something close to what you had in your initial post.

Comment: `DialogBox` or `DialogBoxParam` are very similar to `MessageBox`. Except they allow providing your own event handling function and dialog template.